# Can't play WAV file

Tags: windows, livecode

I create a player on card 1 and set the filename of the player to `path/sound`. I save the standalone application to windows. When I click button to start. The sound doesn't play. What's happening?

This is my code:

Stack:

```
on preOpenStack
      if the platform is "Win32" then 
         set the dontUseQT to true
         set the dontUseQTEffects to true
      end if
end preOpenStack
```

Card :

```
on mouseUp
   set itemDel to slash
   put the effective filename of this stack into realpath
   delete last item of realpath
   if environment() is not "mobile" then
      set the fileName of player "player" to (realpath & slash & "assets/sounds/click.wav")
      set the currentTime of player "player" to 0
      start player "player"
   else
      put realpath & slash & "assets/sounds/click.wav" into tPath
      put "clickbtn" into tChannelName
      mobilePlaySoundOnChannel tPath, tChannelName , "now"
   end if
end mouseUp
```

Comment: You write that you save the standalone to "windows". What does that mean? Do you really save your standalone in `C:\Windows`? That would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't play a wav file in a Player control without QuickTime. Instead, import the sound as a control and use

```
play audioClip "Name of sound.wav"
```

or use the path to the sound:

```
play "path/to/sound.wav"
```

Comment: This code, I use for play background music. I want to use sound for effect.

Comment: @KemChat Sure. Try it.